# UIView Frame View and CGRect Not Working on First Call

Tags: ios, swift

So I am trying to slide a tableview in over top of a lower view, which happens to also to be a uitableview.  I have a sandwich icon to slide it in and a close icon to slide it out.

The button switching works great.  However, when clicking the close button, the first time, the tableview will not slide out, it will basically slid out and right back to where it is.

However subsequent times, after the close icon switches back to sandwich, and then I click again to bring back close, it will slide it out just fine.   Why it not work on the first try.

Below is my code.   As you can see my CGRect is supposed to animate and slide the view to the displaywidth X.

```
@objc func showNewsList(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
    let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
    let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height
    newsIconClose.isHidden = true
    
    

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
newsSourceTable.frame = CGRect(x: displayWidth, y: 0, width: 
        displayWidth, height: displayHeight + 100)
        self.addNewsIcon()
    })

    
}
```

Comment: then you need to show us your close action source, also

Comment: Close action?  This is the close action.  I am trying slide it out of view.

Answer (score 0):

Bingo, figured it out.  For whatever reason, CGRect wasn't liked, but this is.

```
     self.newsSourceTable?.frame.origin.x = 0
```

Comment: haha.. yes. because the animation block is applied to the parameters called. if you set all of them, like when setting frame again, it animates all of them.